# Add an extra page to a PDF document using PDFsharp library

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I am trying to merge PDF documents and add extra pages to some of them. The merge part is working fine and now I am trying to figure out how to add an extra page by passing a link to the preexisting PDF page. How can I pass a link to a PDF page to targetDoc.AddPage(LINK)?

```
    public static void MergePDFs(string targetPath, DataTable pdfs)
    {
        try
        {
            using (PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument targetDoc = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument())
            {
                foreach (DataRow pdf in pdfs.Rows)
                {
                    using (PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(pdf["link"].ToString(), PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < pdfDoc.PageCount; i++)
                        {
                            targetDoc.AddPage(pdfDoc.Pages[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                targetDoc.Save(targetPath);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex);
        }
    }
```

Stamping method

```
using (Stream pdfStream = new FileStream(sourceFileName, FileMode.Open))
{
using (Stream newpdfStream = new FileStream(newFileNameWithPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(pdfStream);
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newpdfStream);
    PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(pageNumber);
    BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    pdfContentByte.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
    pdfContentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 12);
    pdfContentByte.BeginText();
    pdfContentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, inputText, Convert.ToInt32(xCoordinate), Convert.ToInt32(yCoordinate), 0);
    pdfContentByte.EndText();
    pdfStamper.Close();
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure if my answer is what you are looking for. If you would explain what "passing a link to the preexisting pdf page" means I might have to update my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to pass the pdf page to my stamping method and add it back after is stamped. I added my stamping method above

Comment: The stamper uses iTextSharp. You can use iTextSharp to save the stamped page to a stream, open that with PDFsharp and use the stamped page like any other page. It seems your code already saves the stamped PDF in the `newpdfStream` stream and you only have to open that PdfReader.Open() - works with files and streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a new, empty page call `AddPage()` without parameters.

```
targetDoc.AddPage();
```

You might need `Clone()` to create multiple copies of an existing imported page (also add `(PdfPage)`):

```
targetDoc.AddPage((PdfPage)pdfDoc.Pages[i].Clone());
```